# ExtJS - RadioGroup shows two selected items except one

Tags: extjs, radio-button, selecteditem, radio-group

Dears,

I have implemented a pop-up window to be shown by clicking a trigger-button of a textbox, and it has a *radioGroup* in it. in some cases I have to check the radio based on user input.

The problem is that if I try to invoke `radioGroup.setValue()` before opening the popup once, I face with two selected items in *radioGroup*. The issue doesn't occur if open-close the popup before trying to set the checked radio.
Is it a rendering issue or something like that?!

Comment: May you provide some fiddle sample?

Comment: Without any code, I'm assuming you're invoking `setValue` incorrectly... if you're passing an object with a name property, then you're doing it right, and a Fiddle would be helpful.  If you're passing a primitive value and you haven't specified [simpleValue](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html#cfg-simpleValue), that's most likely your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm trying to simplify the case and provide a fiddle.
@incutonez .
No, [setValue](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html#placeholder-setValue) is OK, and I've set [simpleValue](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html#cfg-simpleValue) and [isCheckboxGroup](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html#property-isCheckboxGroup).
The issue is the radioGroup doesn't uncheck the default checked item before rendering and in first show two checked item are there.